# Formula simplification when working with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

There's a pragraph in my books which states the following;

- $3x_2 - 5 \Lambda = 6$

Equal to

- $x_2 = \frac{5}{3} \Lambda + 2$

So $5/3$ and $6/3$, which makes sense because we stopped multiplying $x_2$ by 3, but where did the minus sign go? Why did it become a plus sign? I'd like to know the rules for this.

And the next simplification I can't figure out at all;

- $x_1 + 2*(\frac{5}{3} \Lambda + 2) - 4 \Lambda = 7$

To

- $x_1 = \frac{2}{3} \Lambda + 3$

Unfortunately the study material doesn't explain how they got to any of this, can anyone shed some light?

In case it's important, here's the original formulas;

- $x_1 + 2x_2 - 4x_3 = 7$
- $3x_2 - 5x_3 = 6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few rules for transforming equations

- You can add or subtract the same term on both sides (this can effectively move one term to the other side with sign reversal)
- You can multiply or divide both sides by the same non-zero term
- On either side use the distributive law in both directions to split or combine $()$ expressions or sums of variables (e.g. $3\Lambda + 2\Lambda = 5 \Lambda$).

Regarding your two cases:

In the first you will first add $5 \Lambda$ on both sides and than divide both sides by 3.

Second case: First you may use the distributive law to get rid of $()$ and write
$$2*(\frac{5}{3} \Lambda + 2) = 2\times\frac{5}{3}\times\Lambda + 2\times2.$$ Then you combine the two terms with $\Lambda$, and then 'move' all but $x_1$ to the right hand side and collect the terms without $\Lambda$, i.e. 7 and the -4 from $-2\times 2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it took forever but I finally get it now!